# Como realizar um gráfico de barras vertical com o caracter # em c++?

Tags: c++, gráfico

Realização de um trabalho de C++ aqui da faculdade:

Como realizar um gráfico vertical em barras, ou seja, de baixo para cima, de algum vetor.

Supondo que exista um vetor com algumas posições, por exemplo v[3], sendo que cada posição é um usuário que contenha um valor. O gráfico devera conter essa quantidade.

Supondo que V[0] tenha 5, V[1] tenha 6 e V[2] tenha 4. O total é 15, no caso, então o gráfico deverá ser proporcional, ou seja, 5 é 33,33% e sucessivamente.

Comment: Você podia dar mais detalhes sobre a sua dúvida. E é utilizando qual toolkit? Qt? wxWidgets? WIN32?

Comment: Codeblocks 13.12, WIN32, poderia me dizer o que significa Qt?

Comment: Informações sobre o Qt: http://qt-project.org/

Comment: Não é Qt não, é um programa simples, o professor entrará com os dados dentro dos vetores e o gráfico irá aparecer logo em seguida, na vertical(a parte mais importante), com a porcentagem de cada posição do vetor.

Comment: Eu não entendi a parte do #. Dê mais detalhes.

Comment: @LucasNunes Provavelmente o programa é console, nada de Qt, etc, e o # é usado pra fazer o gráfico, estilo ASCII art.

Answer (score 4):

Se entendi bem, você quer desenhar N barras cada uma com altura H<sub>k</sub>. Como o output é horizontal você tem que ir desenhando um pedaço de cada barra de cada vez antes de pular a linha. Então primeiro encontre o elemento máximo (a barra mais alta) e depois faça esse número de iterações. Em cada uma desenha a barra se seu valor for maior ou igual à iteração atual.

Aqui um código simples que faz isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void printBottomUpBarChart(const std::vector<int>& levels) {
    int highest = *std::max_element(levels.begin(), levels.end());
    for (int level = highest; level > 0; --level) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < levels.size(); ++i) {
            if (levels[i] >= level)
                std::cout << " #";
            else
                std::cout << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Um exemplo de uso:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> lvs;
    lvs.push_back(3);
    lvs.push_back(8);
    lvs.push_back(1);
    lvs.push_back(2);
    lvs.push_back(0);
    lvs.push_back(5);
    printBottomUpBarChart(lvs);
    return 0;
}
```

E o output:

```
   #        
   #        
   #        
   #       #
   #       #
 # #       #
 # #   #   #
 # # # #   #
```

Se tem outros valores e quer desenhar o gráfico sendo proporcional a esse valores mas não usando exatamente eles para o número de #, escale o vetor antes de passar para a função. Sugiro arredondar para cima sempre (`std::ceil(1.0 * x * targetHeight / actualHeight)`).

Comment: Ao invés de `#` acho que também dá para usar `█` (219) e `▄` (220), daí dá para aumentar a resolução do gráfico.

Comment: Também pensei nisso, mas o professor pediu em #, não entendi o motivo.

Comment: @Guilherme Bernal, muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.

Comment: @user8184 deveria ter aceitado como resposta então.